# using Plotly with pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, plotly

I am trying to use **Plotly** with **pycharm** when I run the code (which I toke from the Ploty getting started [page](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/#initialization-for-offline-plotting)  on terminal it is OK but when I use it with pycharm I get error:

"ImportError: No module named 'plotly.graph_objs'; 'plotly' is not a packageé"

[Code on pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo5Pb.png)

Any idea about where could be the problem ? because plotly module works on terminal and not on the editor 
could this problem be related to what is evoqued in this question ?

> Blockquote [Python dynamic objects not defined anywhere? (Plotly lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021683/python-dynamic-objects-not-defined-anywhere-plotly-lib)

Thx

Answer (score 3):

In Pycharm you have to download it.

Go to File --> Settings -->Project --> Project Interpreter --> on the plus right site--> search for your module and download it!

Thats it!!

Comment: I really did that before asking here.
plotly was successfully installed and no thing changed
then I searched of "graph" even if I know that graph should be included in plotly and the response was :
"DEPRECATION: --no-install, --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are deprecated.  See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.
Downloading/unpacking graph
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement graph
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for graph
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log"

Answer (score 3):

Your script is named `plotly.py`. In the first line where you import plotly it loads your script and not the plotly package. Change the name of your script to `plot.py` or something other than plotly and it should work.