# PyCharm showing import error when using plotly module?

Tags: python, pycharm, plotly

[image: imports not resolving]

I am getting a red squiggly line while importing from plotly module even though when I run this script from inside PyCharm (Ctrl-Shift-F10) it works and shows the graph in the web browser. Even ipython shows auto completion for imports:

[image: ipython]

This is how my virtualenv looks:

[image: virtualenv]

This problem seems to have occurred before: [Python dynamic objects not defined anywhere? (Plotly lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021683/python-dynamic-objects-not-defined-anywhere-plotly-lib)

Answer (score 2):

After drilling into the imports a bit I found that the `__init__.py` file in the graph_objs package was too large for default intellisense.
Adding `idea.max.intellisense.filesize=10240` to the custom properties file (`Help -> Edit Custom Properties...`) got it working for me.

Comment: I had this problem when upgrading from Plotly 3 to Plotly 4 when using `import plotly.graph_objects as go`. This seems to have fixed the problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:
Scatter and Layout objects created dynamicly. Therefore pycharm cannot find its definition.

Details:

This is the first include in your py file;

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Layout
```

after that it call **plotly/graph_objs/__init__.py** file ;

```
from plotly.graph_objs.graph_objs import *  # this is protected with __all__
```

after that

```
__all__ = list(graph_reference.CLASSES.keys())
```

This defination is in **plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.py** file. *__all__* is a list of public objects of that module.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

defination of CLASSES in **plotly/graph_referance.py**;

```
CLASSES = _get_classes()
```

In this function it itarates variable named *_BACKWARDS_COMPAT_CLASS_NAMES* and create classes;

```
_BACKWARDS_COMPAT_CLASS_NAMES = {
    ...
    'Scatter': {'object_name': 'scatter', 'base_type': dict},
    ...
    'Layout': {'object_name': 'layout', 'base_type': dict},
    ...
}
```

Comment: So is there a way to get PyCharm to not mark this as a warning?

Comment: I try it in Pycharm 2016.2.3, the problem does not continue. I think it can be fixed in current version.